# Missuse of chmod -R 777 ./

Tags: sudo, system, chmod

I ran something like:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /.
```

In my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS it shows many errors on display, but anyway, the damage was done. Now I can't use `sudo`

```
sudo: error en /etc/sudo.conf, línea 0 mientras carga plugin 'sudoers_policy'
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so sólo tener permisos de escritura por el propietario
sudo: error fatal, no se puede cargar los plugins
```

And besides of that I'm nervous about what else I have broken.

Is there a way to reestablish the right permissions of the system files?

I apologise for the English, that is not my native language.

Comment: yep, it is the same, is there a way to merge both in one, or it's better to left both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to undo that would be a tedious by hand process for which you would need to know all the files original permissions. Save yourself the headache, Use a live USB/CD in conjunction with an external drive to backup your `/home` folder and do a clean fresh install.

Comment: thanks, I was very afraid of that, at least the system is working. have a nice day

Comment: Yes your system did not break from that, but the Operating System is in the fritz in its current state. You might click the check-mark beside my answer to mark it as accepted if it was helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, Im going to reinstall, but i got some databases in mysql, so in order to run the server and the phpmyadmin i ran  the installation cd, mount the unit and execute :

chmod -R 755 . in the directory of mysql 

I tell this in case some have a similar trouble

Comment: One more comment, I try the reinstall, and works whitout sweeping my home directory...
The catch is the software center doesn't work at all, after a quick search here I reinstall the software center but it marks not a few errors, so i'm going to reinstall from zero